# How to remove the text and link from WooCommerce new account email

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, builder

I would like to remove the text and link (You can access your account area to view your orders and change your password here: https://agmart.com.hk/my-account/.) from the WooCommerce default new account email. I am also using the [Decorator – WooCommerce Email Customizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/decorator-woocommerce-email-customizer/) from [WebToffee](https://www.webtoffee.com/) but there is no option to remove the text and link or change the text. May I seek for the advise on proceeding with this, please? Thanks!

```
I have tried to remove the code from the email template both in woocommerce and the Decorator plugin but seems not working, thanks!
```

Comment: This message is from woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-new-account.php -  This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-new-account.php.

Answer (score 0):

As mujuonly already mentioned: You need to overwrite the WooCommerce template `woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-new-account.php`. Changing the text from the `functions.php` is not possible.

You can find more infos about template overwriting here: https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

To overwrite the template, copy the above template to this folder structure: `yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-new-account.php`.

Now you can edit it, update-safe. The text you want to change can be found at line `25`.